# How to eficiently style 4 column with text aligned on left and on right?

Tags: html, css

I have following image which describing what i'm trying to do.

[image]

I have style in list these 4 columns.

DIV 1 and DIV 3 should have text items aligned on the left and DIV 2 and DIV 4 on the right.

A would like to do it simple and efficient as is possible without many ineer div's or table with relave width of list item.

Could somebody tell me haw can i do it in right way?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Your explanation doesn't match your image.. "DIV 1 and DIV 3 should have text items aligned on the left" - in the image Div1 and Div2 are on the left

Comment: You sure you don't want to use a `<table>`? This looks like a good place to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/pwr9evxk/)

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
<div class="left-inner">
    text
</div>
<div class="right-inner">
    num
</div>
</div>
<div id="right">
<div class="left-inner">
    text
</div>
<div class="right-inner">
    num
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left,
#right
{
width: 40%;
}

#left {
float: left;
}
#right {
float: right;
}

.left-inner,
.right-inner
 {
width: 50%;
float: left;    
}

.left-inner {
text-align: left;
background: #ccc;
}
.right-inner {
text-align: right;
background: #f1f1f1;
}
```